# Process Priority value is different in procfs

Tags: process, nice, procfs

For example, let's examine the value of PRI of firefox with ps, and then see what is the value stored in procfs.

```
$ ps -o pid,comm,pri,ni 7000
  PID COMMAND         PRI  NI
 7000 firefox          19   0

$ cat /proc/7000/stat
7000 (firefox) S 1 6447 6447 0 -1 4194304 3162595 624998 158 10 30467 6903 3360 488 20 0 63 0 464836 9472659456 123045 18446744073709551615 94866409246720 94866409429052 140727418541056 0 0 0 0 4096 33572095 0 0 0 17 2 0 0 342 0 0 94866411526576 94866411528296 94866422095872 140727418542495 140727418542520 140727418542520 140727418544095 0
```

According to man proc, we will find the value of PRI in the 18th value (counting from 1), so in this case PRI = 20

I want to know why there is such difference between the output of the `ps` command and the value stored in the /proc stat file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Uh, apparently the `pri` field is exactly 39 minus the value that is visible in `/proc/$pid/stat` (so 39 - 20 = 19). It's also commented as 'not legal as UNIX "PRI"', since

> Unix98 only specifies that a high "PRI" is low priority.

And that doesn't apply there.

But! There are no less than *six* other output formats for the priority, all of which have the raw value either negated or not, plus some constant.
Take a pick. Here's three cats with different `nice` values:

```
$ ps -o pid,rtprio,pri,opri,priority,pri_foo,pri_bar,pri_baz,pri_api,ni,args -Ccat
  PID RTPRIO PRI PRI PRI FOO BAR BAZ API  NI COMMAND
18418      -   0  99  39  19  40 139 -40  19 cat /dev/zero
18419      -  19  80  20   0  21 120 -21   0 cat /dev/zero
18420      -  39  60   0 -20   1 100  -1 -20 cat /dev/zero
```

The comments in the code say that

> Sun and SCO add the `-c` behavior. Sun defines "pri" and "opri".

So there's probably some historical reason to fix the output range to match. `ps -c` uses the `pri` valu here. `priority` is the raw value as the kernel presents it.

The relevant source code file is `ps/output.c`:
 https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/blob/master/ps/output.c#L585

Also: https://superuser.com/questions/286752/unix-ps-l-priority/286761
and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18829350/linux-thread-priority-value

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however I still didn't get some details here. Would you mind telling me why there are so much different priority values? (pri,opri,priority,pri_foo,pri_bar,pri_baz,pri_api) what is the use of all of this? Do we actually need all those different values? @ilkkachu

Comment: Horrifying.  Excellent.

Comment: @ACK_stoverflow, I just re-read this now, almost two and a half years after it was written. I had to stop and stare for a while, and try to convince myself I hadn't seen this in a horrifying dream. Thanks for pinging with the comment...